# Unable to run ActiveRecord Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubygems, rake, bundler

I added the gemfile:

```
gem 'activerecord-reputation-system', require: 'reputation_system'
```

to my Rails app in order to add upvote/downvote functionity to a model (I'm following Railscast #364). I installed the gem with no problems.

I entered 'rails g reputation_system' and rake db:migrate, but the rake was aborted:

```
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 12.3.0, but your 
Gemfile requires rake 12.0.0. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command 
may solve this.
```

I tried it with 'bundle exec', but the rake was aborted again:

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations 
canceled:

Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. 
Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:
```

I updated my gems to see if this was the trouble, but this made no difference.

I can't think of anything else I could do other than finding some way of removing rake 12.3.0 and installing 12.0.0, but this seems illogical.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5 migrations require you to specify the Rails version you’re using (the migration is specified for) at the top of your migration file, as the error states.

This looks like this:

```
class CreateYourModels < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
 ...your migration code
end
```

Where the bit in brackets is the Rails version you're using.

Then try to run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.

Additional explanation: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/01/migrations-are-versioned-in-rails-5.html

Comment: This article tells me that the Rails version is specified in the migration generated, but it doesn't indicate any different terminal command. Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: That’s a good question and I’ve run into that before. There’s no difference in terminal command but I’ll dig into why that might be the case and get back to you. What version of rails is in your gem file btw? In the meantime give the updated code a try in your migration files and let me know if it works.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you meant - update the migration files and then migrate them. I'll try that...

Comment: gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.2'

Comment: Yes, sorry for being unclear. I also noticed I mistyped the top of the file. Edited accordingly.